# Meteor async unexpected token (

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, meteor, npm

I'm using meteor 1.5.1 and I encounter the following bug when trying to import a npm module (kraken-api), server side :

import KrakenClient from 'kraken-api';

```
    > W20170726-22:02:48.177(2)? (STDERR) packages/modules.js:677
    > W20170726-22:02:48.181(2)? (STDERR) 


     const rawRequest = async (url,headers, data, timeout) => { 
     Unexpected token ( 


    >  W20170726-22:02:48.193(2)?
    > (STDERR)     at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    > W20170726-22:02:48.197(2)? (STDERR)     at
    > /home/meteor/project/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:331:30
    > W20170726-22:02:48.204(2)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
    > W20170726-22:02:48.208(2)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach
    > (/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.1.bdxouu++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11) W20170726-22:02:48.211(2)? (STDERR)     at
    > /home/meteor/project/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:158:5
    > W20170726-22:02:48.215(2)? (STDERR)     at
    > /home/meteor/project/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:387:5
    > W20170726-22:02:48.218(2)? (STDERR)     at Function.run
    > (/home/meteor/project/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
    > W20170726-22:02:48.221(2)? (STDERR)     at
    > /home/meteor/project/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:386:11
```

It is expecting something else after the "async" 
line 31 here : 
https://github.com/nothingisdead/npm-kraken-api/blob/master/kraken.js

I'm using nodejs 8.2.1, so await & async should be ok.

Edit : meteor node --version gives me node v4.8.4

If you have any idea

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you somehow figured out, Meteor uses its own copy of node. The objective is to bind a Meteor release to a node version which compatibility is guaranteed.

Therefore whatever the node version on your system, it is not used when running Meteor.

Comment: In fact, async & await are supported by Meteor, despite the node version, I resolved my problem by copying the content of the unique js file of the module directly in my application and this was working. it's a little bit "dirty" but I'll do with that..

Comment: I see, then it is due to the fact that currently Meteor does not transpile npm modules.